# How to make a custom horizontal dashed divider in Material UI?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, divider, sx

I have a divider template and I want to customize it by transforming it into a horizontal dashed divider. But I'm not sure how to override it, especially if I even do an sx edit by applying a borderRadius, it doesn't change the divider.

source code:

```
import * as React from "react";
import List from "@mui/material/List";
import ListItem from "@mui/material/ListItem";
import ListItemText from "@mui/material/ListItemText";
import Divider from "@mui/material/Divider";

const style = {
  width: "100%",
  maxWidth: 360,
  bgcolor: "background.paper"
};

export default function ListDividers() {
  return (
    <List sx={style} component="nav" aria-label="mailbox folders">
      <ListItem button>
        <ListItemText primary="Inbox" />
      </ListItem>
      <Divider sx={{ borderRadius: 1 }} />
      <ListItem button divider>
        <ListItemText primary="Drafts" />
      </ListItem>
      <ListItem button>
        <ListItemText primary="Trash" />
      </ListItem>
      <Divider sx={{ borderRadius: 1 }} />
      <ListItem button>
        <ListItemText primary="Spam" />
      </ListItem>
    </List>
  );
}
```

Current appearance:

[image: Current appearance divider]

Goal appearance of divider:
[image: Dashed divider appearance]

Your responses would indeed help me a lot, especially since I am exploring MUI as of this moment. I am also open to alternatives in terms of Dividers. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

you can use borderStyle:'dashed' as a property in sx :

sx={{borderStyle:'dashed'}}